Is there a way to save Grpc stubs directly as JPA entities without having to create a copy Java object?
When using both gRPC and Spring Boot with JPA, I find myself with the situation where I'm forced to write duplicate Java data transfer objects to represent the same thing, and I'm wondering if there is a better way.
So let's say you have this tika.proto file:
message SaveFetcherRequest {
  string fetcher_id = 1;
  string plugin_id = 2;
  string fetcher_config_json = 3;
}

This will generate a org.apache.tika.SaveFetcherRequest java stub object.
But then JPA uses an Repository that writes from an Entity object.
@Entity
public class Fetcher {
  @Id
  String fetcher_id;
  String plugin_id2;
  String fetcher_config_json;
}

I very much wanted to just use the auto-generated java class without having to re-create that class by hand.
Can such a thing be done?

It's possible that there's already (or you could write) a protoc plugin to generate JPA entities. It's generally not good practice to use protocol buffer types in your application code and better to map between your application types and the wire types.

If you have a SaveFetcherRequest java object, you just need to define how it is to be handled in your JPA environment - it doesn't require another java class at all. Your issue is you don't have anything accessible to put annotations on without another editable class - use an orm.xml to define the mappings and relationships in your SaveFetcherRequest instead.
